# Receiving null value error when providing a value to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am receiving the following error when trying to perform an insert:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Request_Cat_ID', table 'dbo.Request_Categories'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The reason this error is baffling to me is because I have a table setup very similarly where the key column is a string instead of an int. I can insert without a problem to that table. The insert is small and simple, so here's the breakdown:

Model:

```
[Table("Request_Categories")]
public class RequestCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Request_Cat_ID")]
    public int RequestCategoryID { get; set; }
    [Column("Request_Category")]
    public string RequestCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class RequestCategoryViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RequestCategory> RequestCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddRequestCategory(RequestCategory model)
{
    var foo = model.RequestCategoryID; //There is a value that appears here. It does have an int type.
    db.RequestCategories.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json("");
}
```

Where it is passed in from the view:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("AddRequestCategory", "Services", new { area = "services" })',
{
     RequestCategoryID: form.currentTarget.RequestCategoryID.value,
     RequestCategoryName: form.currentTarget.RequestCategoryName.value,
}, AddRow, "json");
```

Any advice or tips are welcome!

Comment: Are you asking why you are getting the error?

Comment: Why and/or how to solve. Like I mentioned, I don't understand why I can't insert to this table yet I can on a table with a different key type.

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to mention a viewmodel being involved, but I don't believe that should make any difference. The use of viewmodels are for other areas of the system that need to bridge more than one table.

Comment: If you are getting the error message saying that you cannot insert the calue null it is as simple as that. The column `Request_Cat_ID` is set to not allow null values. You either need to put a value in for that, or change the table to allow null values.

Comment: While I understand that, I'd like to direct you to the foo variable in the controller where I check the value of the RequestCategoryID, which is linked to Request_Cat_ID in the model. It has a value when I add. Why would I then receive an error saying the value is null?

Comment: Your data is being lost somewhere. Trace it line by line using F10/F11 and you'll see where it's happening.

Comment: Ah I overlooked that I apologize.

Comment: I assume you want SQL Server to auto increment `RequestCategoryID`, so why and with what are you filling it in your view?

Comment: @banging, I've tried to step through it, setting a breakpoint in my controller at 'foo'. However, my application doesn't let me step into either Add or SaveChanges.

Comment: @HenkMollema, At the moment, I do not plan on auto increment. However, should I not find a solution to being able to manually set it, I will have to change my table to auto increment.

Comment: If you don't want SQL server to auto increment, you should decorate `RequestCategoryID` with the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute. EF auto increments primary keys of type `int` by convention.

Comment: @HenkMollema, That worked like a charm. Would you mind writing that up as an answer so I can accept it and provide you with credit deserved?

Comment: @AdamBartz added it as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the [`DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to `RequestCategoryID` since you don't want it to auto increment:

```
[Key]
[Column("Request_Cat_ID")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
[public int RequestCategoryID { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework auto increment `int` primary keys by convention.